# Calculate the intermediate values spread over 125 points - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm having trouble putting together a spreadsheet and I believe there must be a simple way to do it (I'm using Google Sheets).

I have a starting value and an ending value, I need to calculate the intermediate values spread over 125 points. The value can increase or decrease, I just need to find a formula that returns the linear evolution of these points.

My spreadsheet is similar to the table below:

| Point | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6,078 |
| 2 | ? |
| 3 | ? |
| 4 | ? |
| 5 | ? |
| 6 | ? |
| ... | ? |
| 126 | 5,9096 |

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant about "The value can increase or decrease..."? Am I right to assume that the values will be random but will follow a certain tolerance rate to reproduce a linear regression type of data?

Comment: You have listed "excel" and "google-sheets" in your tags. These are quite different platforms, each of which has varying function sets and protocols. Please remove whichever tags are not applicable to your actual situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to use a custom function using Google Apps Script. You can use the following script:

```
/**
 * Fills in the linear series given the range of the first and last values of the series.
 *
 * @param {string} input the range of the first value
 * @param {string} input the range of the last value
 * @return array of the series output
 * @customfunction
 */

function linearFillinFunction(firstValueRange, lastValueRange) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var firstVal = ss.getRange(firstValueRange).getValue(); //Gets the first value of the linear series
  var lastVal = ss.getRange(lastValueRange).getValue(); //Gets the last value of the linear series
  var lastRow = ss.getRange(lastValueRange).getRow(); //Gets the row number of the last value
  var interval = (lastVal - firstVal)/(lastRow-1); //Gets the interval in the linear series
  var out = []; //Sets the output array to empty
  for(i=2; i<lastRow; i++) { //Iterates the series
    out.push([firstVal+=interval]); //Adds the series entry to the output array
  }
  return out;
}
```

To use the custom function, simply place the function in any cell you want and then input the range of the first and last value of the linear series (in A1 notation) as seen below. Please take note that the expected cells to be filled up should be empty.

[image: Setup]

Output:

[image]

Reverse Output:

[image: reverse output]

### References:

If you wish to learn more about creating custom functions, you may want to try browsing:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings...**
- select **Calculation**
- turn on **Iterative calculation**
- hit **<kbd>Save settings</kbd>** button

[image: 9]

- paste this formula into **A3**

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1);
ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)&";";COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()-1)+(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1)-1))-2))));";"));
"##"));ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)+(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1)-1))-2)* (INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(
)&":A")));1;1)-INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1))/(ROWS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));); IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&
":A"));));1;1)-1)))* (ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)))-(ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&
":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)))* (100/(((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(
N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1));"<>""")+1)-1)* 100))))/ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(
FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)));"0,0000")))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tB56j00WvECmpXgCYfcmXsizotfEb5StpcVwWxpf_pk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: linear fill in...

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you want whole-number values only or, if not, to what precision the intermediate values should be. But the following formula in some cell with at least 125 rows open below it will do the trick:

`=ArrayFormula(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(126,1,6078*100,(59096-6078)/125*100)/100))`

Of course, you can set the start and end values in two cells and reference the cells instead.

The reason everything is multiplied by 100 and then divided by 100 is because, most often, the intermediate raw values will include decimal portions while `SEQUENCE` only works with whole numbers. So multiplying by 100 and then dividing later by 100 allows the underlying numbers to go to a precision of 1/100 (or two decimal points) before `ROUNDUP` is applied.

If you want to see the decimal values, remove `ROUNDUP( )`.

If you want greater precision, increase 100 to 1000 (etc.) in each of the three locations it appears within the formula.